# Exportar GridView para CSV em arquivo de excel / VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, gridview, csv

Seguindo exemplos encontrados na web e até mesmo no stackoverflow eu preenchi o botão `btnGerarCSV` dessa forma.

```
Protected Sub btnGerarCSV_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnGerarCSV.Click
     Dim sb As New StringBuilder
     Dim gv As New GridView
            Try
                Page.Response.Clear()
                Page.Response.Buffer = True
                Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;Pedido_" & Session("ddlPedido") & ".csv")
                Page.Response.Charset = ""
                Page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"                

                grdPedido.DataSource = Session("dtPedidosColetados")

                For i As Integer = 0 To grdPedido.Columns.Count - 1
                    'Adiciona separador por vírgula
                    sb.Append(grdPedido.Columns(i).HeaderText + ","c)
                Next
                'Adiciona nova linha
                sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

                For i As Integer = 0 To grdPedido.Rows.Count - 1
                    For j As Integer = 0 To grdPedido.Columns.Count - 1
                        'Adiciona separador por  vírgula
                        sb.Append(grdPedido.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text + ","c)
                    Next
                    'Adiciona nova linha
                    sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
                Next

                Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
                Response.Flush()
                Response.End()

            Catch ef As ThreadAbortException
                Exit Try
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Sub
```

A minha página funciona da seguinte forma: O usuário escolhe Data Inicial e Data Final e seleciona o botão buscar. Então o `grdPedido` é preenchido e exibido em tela. Após isso dois botões são exibidos, um para exportar para excel em planilha, que está funcionando corretamente e um botão para CSV.

Porém o que me acontece é que ao chegar na linha `For i As Integer = 0 To grdPedido.Columns.Count - 1` o número de colunas é = 0, mesmo o grid retornando a consulta normalmente.

Já alterei o código de diversas formas, mas cai sempre nesse mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito brigar com esse código, encontrei uma forma de resolver o problema das colunas sempre retornarem 0

Inseri um `Directcast` para converter o `gv.DataSource` em um objeto e então utilizar outro `Directcast` para transformar o objeto em um `DataTable`

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DirectCast(DirectCast(gv.DataSource, System.Object), System.Data.DataTable).Columns.Count - 1
                'Adiciona separador por vírgula
                'sw.Write(gv.Columns(i).HeaderText + ","c) Como estava antes
                sw.Write(DirectCast(DirectCast(gv.DataSource, System.Object), System.Data.DataTable).Columns(i).ColumnName + ","c)
            Next
            'Adiciona nova linha
            sw.Write(vbCr & vbLf)

            For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
                'For j As Integer = 0 To gv.Columns.Count - 1 Como estava antes
                For j As Integer = 0 To DirectCast(DirectCast(gv.DataSource, System.Object), System.Data.DataTable).Columns.Count - 1
                    'Adiciona separador por  vírgula
                    sw.Write(gv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text + ","c)
                Next
                'Adiciona nova linha
                sw.Write(vbCr & vbLf)
            Next
```

Não sei se é a forma mais simples, mas só assim consigo obter o retorno das colunas.